# How to select random node with xmlstarlet in bash?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xmlstarlet

Bash, ubuntu linux.
How to select random node with xmlstarlet in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet sel -B -t -c "//node()[$RANDOM mod last() + 1]" input.xml
```

The `-B` strips whitespace nodes, which you probably don't want to select...

---

I also tried using [math:random()](http://exslt.org/math/functions/random/index.html) defined at exslt.org:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N math=http://exslt.org/math -B -t --var r='math:random()' \
 -c '//node()[round($r * last()) + 1]' -n input.xml
```

But it appears to use the same seed every time.